# Link on the center but icon on the right

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have a problem with position. I want to make the icons on the right align while links are on the center of navigation. But seems like I hit a wall.

This is my HTML

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="home.html"> HOME </a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a href="about.html"> ABOUT </a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a href="music.html"> MUSIC </a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a href="gallery.html"> GALLERY </a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a href="contact.html"> CONTACT </a> 
        </li>
        <li class="navimage"> <a href="#"> <img src="abc.jpg" /> </a> 
        </li>
        <li class="navimage"> <a href="#"> <img src="abc.jpg" /> </a> 
        </li>
        <li class="navimage"> <a href="#"> <img src="abc.jpg" /> </a> 
        </li>
        <li class="navimage"> <a href="#"> <img src="abc.jpg" /> </a> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and this is my CSS

```
#nav {
    border-bottom:2px solid #FFF;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
}
#nav li {
    display:inline;
}
#nav a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#nav a:hover {
    color:#DEB887;
}
.navimage img {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    border-radius:50%;
    -webkit-border-radius:50%;
    -moz-border-radius:50%;
    -ms-border-radius:50%;
    -o-border-radius:50%;
}
.navimage img a {
    text-align:right;
}
```

here is the jsfiddle to check.
http://jsfiddle.net/zN92c/

Comment: i dont understand the question, can you explain further?

Comment: I need my image on the right of navigation bar. That's all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
.navimage img a {
    text-align:right;
}
```

With:

```
.navimage {
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your css

```
.navimage img a
```

is being aligned right. But the list item itself has no position, Try floating it to the right using:

```
.navimage { float: right; }
```

That would alight the list item to the right.